# NSUserDefaults save and reload while using app but reset when app is restarted

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I have a method to increment a counter if it is the first time a user has been messaged on the particular day. Code below:

```
//here we decide if to increment it or not
-(BOOL)canIncrementCountForUser: (NSString *)user {

    //erase the dictionary if it's a new day
    [self flushDictionaryIfNeeded];

    //load up a dictionary
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [defaults objectForKey:@"uniqueSentToday"];

    NSLog(@"%@", [dictionary allKeys]);

    //if empty it's a yes
    if([dictionary count]==0){
        NSLog(@"empty dictionary");
        NSLog(@"First message for %@ today!",user);
        NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
        [dictionary setObject:now forKey:user]; //do I need to set it back again?
        [defaults synchronize];
        return YES;

    }

    //if it's not empty it's only a yes if the key doesn't exist
    else {

        //not in dict so unique
        if(![dictionary objectForKey:user]){
            NSLog(@"First message for %@ today!",user);
            NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
            [dictionary setObject:now forKey:user]; //do I need to set it back again?
            [defaults synchronize];
            return YES;

        }


        else {

            NSLog(@"Already messaged %@ today!",user);
            return NO;



        }




    }


}

-(void)flushDictionaryIfNeeded{

    //set dictionary
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [defaults objectForKey:@"uniqueSentToday"];

    if([dictionary count]>0) {

        //get any date
        NSDate *aDate = nil;
        NSArray *values = [dictionary allValues];
        aDate = [values objectAtIndex:0];

        NSDateComponents *otherDay = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitEra|NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:aDate];
        NSDateComponents *today = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitEra|NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:[NSDate date]];
        if([today day] == [otherDay day] &&
           [today month] == [otherDay month] &&
           [today year] == [otherDay year] &&
           [today era] == [otherDay era]) {

            NSLog(@"Don't flush");
        }

        else {

            NSLog(@"It's a new day! erase dictionary!");
            [dictionary removeAllObjects];
            [defaults synchronize];

        }

    }

}
```

If a user is messaged a NSDate object will be created with the user's username as the key. If a key doesn't exist the counter can be incremented and the key is added, if it does exist the method returns false. I also have a method to erase all the contents if it's a new day. The code is all working fine and it seems like the NSMutableDictionary is being saved to the application fine when the program is being used but when I restart the app the dictionary will be empty. Can someone give me a pointer on why this might be happening? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You modified the `dictionary` but never set back the `defaults`... You need:

```
[defaults setObject:dictionary forKey:@"uniqueSentToday"];
```

to save the defaults.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the dictionary back in the user defaults as the dictionary you receive is immutable. Although you set it as mutable, changes will not be reflected in the user defaults original stored dictionary.